# omp parallel for loop (reduction to find max) ran slower than serial codes

Tags: openmp

I am new in using OpenMP.
I think that use max reduction clause to find the max element of an array is not such a bad idea, but in fact the parallel for loop ran much slower than serial one.

```
int main() {
double sta, end, elapse_t;
int bsize = 46000;
int q = bsize;
int max_val = 0;
double *buffer;
buffer = (double*)malloc(bsize*sizeof(double));
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
    buffer[i] = rand()%10000;

sta = omp_get_wtime();
//int i;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(max : max_val)
for(int i=0;i<q; i++)
{
    max_val = max_val > buffer[i] ? max_val : buffer[i];
}
end = omp_get_wtime();
printf("parallel maximum time %f\n", end-sta);

sta = omp_get_wtime();
for(int i=0;i<q; i++)
{
    max_val = max_val > buffer[i] ? max_val : buffer[i];
}
end = omp_get_wtime();
printf("serial maximum time   %f\n", end-sta);

free(buffer); 
return 0;}
```

Compile command

```
gcc-7 kp_omp.cpp -o kp_omp -fopenmp
```

Execution results

```
./kp_omp 
parallel maximum time 0.000505
serial maximum time   0.000266
```

As for the CPU, it is an Intel Core i7-6700 with 8 cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you parallelise a loop openMP needs to perform some operations, for example creating the threads. Those operations result in some overhead and this in turns implies that, for each loop, there is a minimum number of iterations under which it is not convenient to parallelise.

If I execute your code I obtain the same results you have:

```
./kp_omp
parallel maximum time 0.000570
serial maximum time   0.000253
```

However if I modify bsize in line 8 such that

```
int bsize = 100000;
```

I obtain

```
./kp_omp
parallel maximum time 0.000323
serial maximum time   0.000552
```

So the parallelised version got faster than the sequential. Part of the challenges you encounter when you try to speedup the execution of a code is to understand when it is convenient to parallelise and when the overhead of the parallelisation would kill your expected gain in performance.